# How to get custom data from receiver

Tags: java, google-play-services, chromecast

I'm attempting to integrate Chromecast into our app and I'm running into an issue with getting data from the receiver when joining an already running application.

When first launching the application i set meta date with the RemoteMediaPlayer using

```
 public class CastMessageStream extends RemoteMediaPlayer {    
    public void setMetadata(GoogleApiClient apiClient, CastingObject castingObject, String seriesId, String description, String episodeNumber, String title) {
        JSONObject payload = _initJsonObject(COMMAND_KEY_SET_METADATA);
        try {
            payload.put(KEY_SUB_TITLE, castingObject.castingSubUrl);
            payload.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            payload.put(KEY_SERIES_ID, seriesId);
            payload.put(KEY_EPISODE_NUMBER, episodeNumber);
            payload.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
            payload.put(KEY_VIDEO_HEADER, castingObject.description);
           sendMessage(apiClient, payload.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Send messages to the reciever using the NAMESPACE
 */
private final void sendMessage(GoogleApiClient apiClient, String message)
        throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException {
    Cast.CastApi.sendMessage(apiClient, NAMESPACE, message);
}
```

Code for joining the already running application

```
 Cast.CastApi.launchApplication(googleApiClient, APP_ID).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult applicationConnectionResult) {
            mMessageStream = new CastMessageStream();
            MediaInfo mediaInfo =  mMessageStream.getMediaInfo();
            MediaStatus mediaStatus = mMessageStream.getMediaStatus();
            JSONObject jsonObject = mediaInfo.getCustomData(); // Returns null
            MediaMetadata metadata = mediaInfo.getMetadata(); // Returns null
            ....
        }
    });
```

How do I get custom information from the receiver. I have it working on iOS so i know its possible.

Comment: What is mMessageStream? (b.t.w., you may want to wrap the code inside your onResult() in a conditional statement to be executed only if applicationConnectionResult.getStatus().isSuccess() is true)

Comment: @AliNaddaf I have it wrapped but for the sake of simplicity i took it out in the question. I edited the question, mMessageStream is a CastMessageStream which extends RemoteMediaPlayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are extending the functionality of the `RemoteMediaPlayer` and overriding its `sendMessage()`. That is actually not recommended for the task that you have in mind; if you want to send additional data with your media, you need to use, for example, the `customData` field that is available in various calls and objects . For example, `MediaInfo` object can have `customData` and you can add these additional fields there, so can a number of control commands like `load(), play(), pause()`, .... If you choose to override the RemoteMediaPlayer's `sendMessage()` then you need to handle the additional functionality on the receiver side as well.

Comment: Ali sorry for the confusion. RemoteMediaPlayer doesn't have a sendMessage method. Its my own method that I just updated the question with. I send the custom message using Cast.CastApi.sendMessage(..). Am I wrong in thinking the receiver should be able to send me back the Custom data it was sent without any additional implementation on the receiver side?

Comment: Looks like you are using a custom namespace (I don't know what NAMESPACE in your code is, but I m guessing that is a custom value). If so, you are on your own to do on the receiver what you want to do (e.g. when you get that, broadcast that to all connected senders). Custom namespaces are there for you to define what they mean and provides a way for you to communicate, framework just sends the message and what needs to be done with it is up to you. Why don't you use the customData that I suggested (defined on, say, MediaInfo)? If you use that, then framework can handle the rest for you.