# How to get custom data back from Cast Reciever?

Tags: javascript, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to integrate JavaScript application with Google Chrome API.
I'm sending `customData` in `MediaInfo` instance like this:

```
var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(src, type);
mediaInfo.customData = {'key': 'value'}
var loadRequest = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
this.apiSession.loadMedia(loadRequest, onMediaDiscovered, onCastError);
```

Now I'm trying to read my custom data, when I join existing cast session:

```
var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(
        sessionRequest,
        sessionJoinedListener,
        receiverListener);

sessionJoinedListener: function(session) {
    // how to read customData here?
}
```

I inspected session object and it's properties and children, but it does not have `customData` included. It has `session.media[0].customData` property, but it's null. Also I tried `session.media[0].media`, but it does not have data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver#events), applications can always customize these sender view of the receiver by using [`customizedStatusCallback`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.MediaManager#customizedStatusCallback) and include sub-states in the [`customData`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.MediaManager.LoadRequestData#customData) field. It enables the sender and receiver to easily extend the media protocol without having to use a new namespace with custom messages. You can check on this related SO thread: [How to get custom data from reciever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210712/how-to-get-custom-data-from-reciever)

Comment: This method is unreliable. It works only upon first request. If a user refreshes the page, attached `customData` is now null by unknown reason.